# Newline between html element breaks html layout

Tags: html, css, newline, space

I know that a newline in html between elements is treated as space, but I think this is pretty scary when you try to play with responsive layout.

For example, here we have the expected and correct behaviour, but to obtain it I had to remove the newline in the html between the element:
https://jsfiddle.net/xew2szfu/1/

```
<div class="recommend-friend__dialog">You should see only me</div><div class="recommend-friend__dialog recommend-friend__dialog--variant">... but NOT ME!</div>
```

Here I wrote the html with a newline, as you normally do, and everything got broken:
https://jsfiddle.net/rL1fqwkc/1/

```
<div class="recommend-friend__dialog">You should see only me</div>
<div class="recommend-friend__dialog recommend-friend__dialog--variant">... but NOT ME!</div>
```

I know I can fix the problem with a float: left, but I wonder if I missed something, the default behaviour sounds really incorrect to me.

Comment: you can control this with CSS, there is nothing wrong with the markup

Comment: I know I can control it with css and I also know the work around. I just wonder if this is the normal behaviour, since if I use 2 children element having 50% width each I expect they fit in the same line. The opposite seems wrong

Comment: `inline-block` behaves nasty when you leave whitespace between. This has been covered many times on articles on the web. Lots of ways to resolve, easiest is to float your children.

Comment: inline-block is practically the same as float:left, why not use it?

Comment: @SetSailMedia can you please link some articles about this specific topic? float property is nasty, since you need to add clearfix, that is why I usually prefer using inline-block property if I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `inline-block` puts a space in between elements, and with the space the second div moves down, since it can't fit on the line any more.

There are many ways to combat this. As you said, float is one of them. [This excellent CSS Tricks article is a great help,](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but I'll go over the ones you probably want:

### Negative margin:

```
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Very simple, you can have a nice html format, but moves the element over to hide the space.

### Set the font-size to 0:

```
.recommend-friend__slider{
  font-size: 0;
}
.recommend-friend__dialog {
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Or, my personal favorite, skip the inline block and use flexbox instead.

Comment: I don't think inline-block put a space in between elements, since my fiddles prove that the extra space is added by the html newline.
+1 for the font-size solution... basically the spaces generated by the html have width 0

Comment: @RubenRizzi you are correct, the inline-block itself isn't putting the space, the space is being added because of the newline. But it is fixed in the same way.